# Python script leaking memory

Tags: python, mysql, memory-management, memory-leaks, nltk

I'm running this code on my server to extract noun phrases (of a sort) 
from some rss feed content. I'm running it on a Web Faction server and it's leaking memory. Any pointers as to how this works or if it's my code at all so i could fix it would be greatly appreciated. The code is:

```
import MySQLdb
import nltk, re, pprint

def RgxChunk(document):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    grammar = "NP: {<RB>?<DT>?<JJ.*>*<NN.*>*}"
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    sentences = [cp.parse(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences;

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="HOST", user="USER" ,  passwd="PASS", db="DB")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor2 = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `rss_posts` WHERE length(`text`) > 100 AND `link` LIKE 'http%'")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    text = row[6]
    parsed = RgxChunk(text)
    insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO `nltk_terms` VALUES'
    insert_values = ''
    for sent in parsed:
        for word in sent:
            if isinstance(word, nltk.tree.Tree): 
                if word.node =='NP':
                    wordcount = len(word)
                    if(wordcount == 1):
                        thephrase = db.escape_string(word[0][0].lower())
                    elif(wordcount > 1):
                        thephrase = word[0][0]
                        for i in range(1,wordcount):
                            thephrase = thephrase + ' ' +word[i][0]
                        thephrase = db.escape_string(thephrase.lower())     
                    thelink = db.escape_string(row[2])
                    insert_values = insert_values + "('" + thelink + "','" + thephrase + "','" + thephrase + thelink + "'),"
    insert_sql = insert_sql + insert_values[:-1]
    cursor2.execute(insert_sql)
    db.commit()
    print str(x+1) + ' articles processed of ' + str(numrows)
```

Comment: Python uses reference counting and automatic garbage collection so nothing should really leak unless if you have a circular structure in which every element is referenced by some other element in the structure. How do you know that you have a memory leak? Do you think the disk cache could be causing it? See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ The reason I ask is because MySQL is known to have some disk cache methods to make retrieval faster and that may make it seem like you're running out of memory.

Comment: My advice: start deleting lines without causing an error and see if it still 'leaks'. When it does not leak any more you found a hint. I can not run this program and this is way too complex for me to know what happens. If you can cut it down to about 5 lines you are more likely to receive an answer because more people will understand it and can look for a solution.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll take a look at it line by line. I wish i was good enough to cut this down to 5 lines of code!!

Comment: Yo are not closing neither db connection nor cursors. Maybe if you are executing more than once this code, it can be a problem